# Without clearing the existing records on Ajax call - DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using DataTables plug-in to retrieve data from a mysql table and display them. For that I am using their server-side processing code to retrieve all data. So far it's working fine. Now, I am checking the database  every minute whether new record is been inserted or not. I am calling data table function if new record is been inserted in database. At the time its clearing entire records and displaying the records with newly inserted records so its look like entire page loads. Can we do without clearing the existing  data? or can we append the newly inserted record into existing record without clearing the record? Or how can I process this one?

Here is my code

```
$('#example').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing": false,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "iDisplayLength":10,
                    "bDeferRender": true,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bSort": false,
                    "bInfo": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": #PHP_PATH#/json_data"
                   });
```

Comment: if its a single / few rows you can try getting them manually with jquery ajax and add manually using the `fnAddData`

Comment: @Daniel- most probably it will be a single/two rows. bt in their document `fnAddData` (http://datatables.net/ref#fnAddData) is suitable for client-side processing only.

Comment: What are you using bServerSide Processing for?

Comment: @LearneR,  Well... you could try, see if the sort/filter takes that newly added row into account... if so i guess its ok... (worst case scenario you can try using `fnUpdate` with a dummy value to update the table data source)

Answer (score 1):

For what you are trying to achieve, I'd also recommend investigating about SignalR - It's awesome!

What are you using `bServerSide` Processing for?

The first time your page is generated and sent to the client, the datatable is rendered with what was then latest data. After that, on every subsequent ajax call, if your server sent you back just the new data, all you have to do is call the below method in the success/complete callback.

```
function AddRow(row) {
    $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData([
        row[0],
        row[1],
        row[2]]);
}
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    success: function(data) {
        //assuming data = ["COL.1", "COL.2", "COL.3"]
        AddRow(data);
    }
    //...
});​
```